# Bash script gui ! How to fix?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to make a text gui use bash script
Here is my code !

```
  #!/bin/bash
red='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0;37m'
clear
#<-Main Menu
echo -e "
#---------------------------------#
|            $red Hello  $NC      |        
#---------------------------------#
| 1: Choice 1                     |     
#---------------------------------#
"
```

output

```
#---------------------------------#
|                Hello        |        #Here is it
#---------------------------------#
| 1: Choice 1                     |               
#---------------------------------#
Your choice is ?(number):
```

how to fix it ? :c

Comment: How to fix ... what? The spacing issue on the second line? Have you perhaps tried to use the colours you specified in variables inside your `echo`?

Comment: @NguyễnMinhNhân Please use the [edit] button to add information.

Comment: @ghoti yes , i tried it

Comment: The variable name `$red` is for characters long, but in the output, the colour change has length 0.

Comment: Use `dialog --menu 'Main menu' 10 20 5 1 'choice 1' 2 'choice 2' 0 exit
` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about restructuring? Something like this, perhaps?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function showmenu() {
        # options:
        #   $1 - menu name (string)
        #   $2 - name of argument array
        red='\033[0;31m'
        NC='\033[0;37m'
        printf '#'; printf '%.0s-' {1..33}; printf '#\n'
        printf '|'; n=${#1}; printf "${red}%$((16+n/2))s${NC}" "$1"; printf " %${n}s" " "; printf '|\n'
        printf '#'; printf '%.0s-' {1..33}; printf '#\n'
        local -n items="${2}"
        local count=0
        for item in "${items[@]}"; do
          printf '| %-2s %-29s|\n' "$((++count))." "$item"
        done
        printf '#'; printf '%.0s-' {1..33}; printf '#\n'
}

testitems=(foo bar "This is a longer item")

showmenu "Hello there" testitems
read -p 'Your choice is ?(number): ' choice
```

You can of course do more math to size your menu based on input content if you feel the urge.